# Presto different git repos and sites

Tags: presto, trino

Here is two link for different version of same project.
Both repos look actual, use same licensee and actually look very similar.
https://github.com/prestodb/presto

https://github.com/trinodb/trino

Can some one explain what happened, which is official one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2019 three of the original Facebook Presto team members Martin Traverso, Dain Sundstrom, and David Phillips formed the “Presto Software Foundation”. This foundation is meant to oversee their fork of the official project. The Presto fork is often referred to as prestosql online.

Taken from https://blog.openbridge.com/what-is-facebook-presto-presto-database-or-prestodb-a-powerful-sql-query-engine-77d4c4a66d4

From 2020, this question will never appear again.
PRESTO community rebrand community version to https://trino.io.
Exactly to avoid any cross interactions with Facebook version.

Comment: Also note https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html